# Operator = function and an add function cant seem to coexist

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm having an issue with two of my functions. I have an `operator =` method as well as an `add` method. They work fine on their own, as in I can only use one or the other during one compile. For example I need to comment out the `add` function in order for the `operator =` method to work and vice versa. The errors I'm getting 10 `no match for 'operator=' in 'c = (&a)->HUGE_INT::add(((HUGE_INT&)(&b)))'`

```
     HUGE_INT HUGE_INT::operator=(HUGE_INT &orig)
        {
        //code
         return *this;
        }

        HUGE_INT HUGE_INT::add(HUGE_INT &a)
        {
         //code
         return object;
        }

//client
    HUGE_INT a(9999999),b(1111),c,d;
       c = a.add(b);
       d = a;
```

Comment: Can you post the simplest example that depicts the error -- code that you think should compile but does not because of the specific error you are asking about.

Comment: like i said the functions work fine when theyre the only one being used in the client, but when there both being called is the problem

Comment: I see it now, `add` returns a temporary and `operator=` requires a non-const reference. You can't form a non-const reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are returning by value from `add`, and taking the argument to `operator=` by non-const reference.

The temporary object returned from `add` is an rvalue, and so it cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Unless you are doing something very strange, you probably want to change `operator=` to take its argument by reference to const:

```
    HUGE_INT& HUGE_INT::operator=(HUGE_INT const& orig)
    {
    //code
     return *this;
    }
```

(I also changed it to return by reference, as this is the standard signature for `operator=`.)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code for you, ofcourse it does nothing now as in your example but it compiles.
The reason is that you need to specify the argument of the '=' operator as constant and  as stated by the other posters you should also return a reference to the object.

```
class HUGE_INT
{
public:
HUGE_INT(){this->var = 0;}
HUGE_INT(int v){this->var = v;};

HUGE_INT& operator=(const HUGE_INT &orig)
{

 return *this;
}

HUGE_INT add(HUGE_INT &a)
{
    HUGE_INT object;
 return object;
}

private:
    int var;
};


int main()
{


//client
HUGE_INT a(9999999),b(1111),c,d;
   c = a.add(b);
   d = a;
}
```

To get a better understanding check out a[tutorial](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) on operator overloading

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator=` should be returning a reference as well as taking a const reference; that is, it should have a signature `HUGE_INT& HUGE_INT::operator=(const HUGE_INT& orig)`.

As a side note, it's really bad C++ style to use all caps for class names. All capitals are generally reserved for macros.